Error loading trimmed video produced by FFMPEG
I've been trying to trim a video using FFMPEG within some javascript code.
The code executes without throwing any errors.
  try {
    const command = `ffmpeg -i ${
      CROPPING_DIR + CROPPED_VIDEO_PREFIX + id + ".mp4"
    } -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:06 -c copy ${
      CROPPING_DIR + TRIMMED_VIDEO_PREFIX + id + ".mp4"
    }`;
    console.log(command);
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(command);
    return "NA";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error executing ffmpeg command:", error);
  }

In VsCode, I am unable to view the trimmed video. Instead I see 'An error occurred while loading the video file'.
Viewing from the file explorer, no video frames are displayed, but I can see the video progress bar moving.
I've attempted a number of FFMPEG commands but am getting the same result.
ffmpeg -i C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Other/project/code/project/app/cropping_images/_cropped_d372d8ff-84c8-4cab-9359-513ee6ad7536.mp4 -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:06 -c copy C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Other/project/code/project/app/cropping_images/_trimmed_d372d8ff-84c8-4cab-9359-513ee6ad7536.mp4

ffmpeg -i C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Other/project/code/project/app/cropping_images/_cropped_87f094f2-b06f-4c21-bd41-ae5e4ca222ae.mp4 -ss 1.05 -to 2.45 -c copy C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Other/project/code/project/app/cropping_images/_trimmed_87f094f2-b06f-4c21-bd41-ae5e4ca222ae.mp4

ffmpeg -i C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Other/project/code/project/app/cropping_images/_cropped_f5b89e96-3efc-4a6e-bba4-428751fb38eb.mp4 -ss 0.00 -to 6.93 -c:v copy -c:a copy C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Other/project/code/project/app/cropping_images/_trimmed_f5b89e96-3efc-4a6e-bba4-428751fb38eb.mp4


Had you looked in your browser’s debug console you would’ve seen a couple of errors:
"await" is designed for async functions but exec() is sync, so remove it from this line...
const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(command);

And this return in the middle of nowhere, is illegal so comment it out...
return "NA";

So fixing these two issues is a good place to start!
Oh and do remove all try{} catch{} from your code until the console is no longer reporting any errors.
The try{} catch{} is good for unforeseen errors that may emerge during runtime, such as a malformed URL/URI etc. You add those LATER if and where needed.
But first you must eliminate ALL red errors displayed in the debug console so that your plane can get off the ground! :)

I promisify exec so I can use await with it. If an error occurred I would get the console.error read out. console.error("Error executing ffmpeg command:", error), which I don't. Returning "NA" should not contribute to the issue I'm having.
